# UIAutomation Instrument Exception "Target app is not frontmost"

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, instruments, cllocationmanager, ios-ui-automation

I have an iOS5 iPad app that uses `CLLocationManager` that I'm testing with `UIAutomation`.

Before I run my test script, I manually press "OK" on the dialog that iOS presents when I use CLLocationManager.

Occassionally, my test scripts will fail to start.  I press the "Play" icon in `Instruments`, and nothing happens for 12 seconds.  Then, I get the following exception:

```
Target app is not frontmost
```

Once this happens, I usually have to restart to get instruments to work again.

I used to get this same exception when I left the `CLLocationManager` dialog in front of my application.  Does anyone have any idea about how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
    //Handling Externally Generated Alerts
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
    var title = alert.name();
    UIALogger.logWarning("Alert with title ’" + title + "’ encountered!");
    if (title == "Add Something") {
        alert.buttons()["Add"].tap();
        return true; // bypass default handler
    }
    return false; // use default handler
}

Use this code to handle location alert
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when an alert view pops up before the app finishes launching fully. It's a bug with automation.

Comment: Handle alert to remove this error, refer Automating_User_Interface_Testing_With_Instruments pdf